# ERROR Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication()

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to run a react-native project of someone else's in my android simulator. after installing all the dependencies and copy and pasting the src folder I'm getting this error and I've no idea what to do as i've been trying to solve this for 2 days.
`

```
 ERROR  Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/
1) Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the above link for details)
2) Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes`
```

I tried soo many solutions like cd ./android && ./gradlew clean.. etc but no command is useful.

Comment: Check for possible compile time error in your code. Some object may be undefined.

Answer (score 8):

I had this message and apparently, there is an error in your code, it just doesn't know what's wrong.

What I did is run my project using `expo start -c` to clear the cache and then the real error was been printed on my terminal.

Hope I could help you!

Comment: If i could help you, please consider to accept this answer by clicking on the "✅" button right there!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native
```

And this works for me

```
yarn cache clean
npx expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened In Expo Project due to the 'react-native-reanimated' Library
Here is the Installation for 'react-native-reanimated'
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/

Before Installation  run expo start -c to Clear Cache

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you have some code that requires native functionality (in my case I was implementing Apple Sign-In and had a need for @react-native-firebase/auth) which requires the app to be installed with expo run:ios (or android) on the simulator (or through XCode). So, just run the above command or comment out that code if the error's root is something similar to what I mentioned.
I hope it will be helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change variable names like dbName dbVersion and got same error,
then I realized that I was using same path inside more than one class but was updating only one, after updating them all error gone.

```
  export default class Constants {
  static DB_NAME = 'new1.db'
  static DB_VERSION = '1.0'
  static DB_SIZE = 200000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just clear the cache and restart .If you are using ios simulator ,go to the device under this erase all content and setting and restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

it looks odd but I've faced this issue too after I tried to install my project with `npx expo start`
now I tried `yarn ios` (stands for `expo run:ios`) and the issue have gone

Answer (score 0):

I know its not the same cause of the problem, but i am sure someone that needs this answer will get here.

In case you are using Firebase and this error occurs to you, and you are trying to use multiple firebase projects in your app, its probably that Firebase is confused on which one he needs to use as the [DEFAULT] project.

To solve this issue you just need to add a name to the second project you added like this :

```js
// Primal firebase app [DEFAULT]
const app_firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Secondary firebase app
const secondaryApp = initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
```

for more information check the official firebase documentation : [Use multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#web)